# Unexpected dot from helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following routings

```
PosTracker::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"

  resources :pos
  resources :apis

  match 'update_data' => 'home#update', :as => :update, :via => :get
  root :to => "home#index"

end
```

Now, when using the `link_to` helper method:

```
link_to "text", pos_path(starbase)
```

I get the following route `/pos.13` instead of `/pos/13`. Obviously, this won't produce valid output. How can I fix this?

Edit: Relevant controller:

```
class PosController < ApplicationController
  # GET /pos
  # GET /pos.xml
  def index
    #do stuff        

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @pos }
    end
  end

  # GET /pos/1
  # GET /pos/1.xml
  def show
    @pos = Pos.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @pos }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: In your controller what does your respond_to look like?

Comment: there you go. The `#do stuff` is just some lookups.

Comment: Is your model `class Po` or `class Pos`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me like Rails is recognizing pos_path as your #index action url helper. Generally it will take the symbol you pass to resources and singularize it for a #show action.

The url helper you want to use would be

```
link_to "text", po_path(starbase)
```

You can generally find the name of the helper methods by running

```
rake routes
```

Or to get the helper for a specific controller

```
rake routes CONTROLLER=pos
```

Comment: Ugh, thank you so much! I was having this same problem myself. Suddenly a bunch of different links were being rendered with .'s instead of /'s before the ID and I had no clue as to why. Turns out I had mistyped an s in the path making it a plural path and then copied the link to various spots making them all invalid. I thought I had somehow really messed something up with my routes!